# Zend_Mail with Office 365 failing

Tags: php, zend-framework, smtp, office365, zend-mail

We have switched from Comcast to Office 365 for sending email from our web application. I'm using Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp from ZF v1.12. Upon switching from Comcast credentials to Office 365 credentials, I am now unable to send mail. Here is my code...

```
$config = array('auth' => 'login',
            'ssl' => 'tls',
            'username' => 'office365username',
            'password' => 'office365password',
            'port' => 587);

$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.office365.com', $config);
```

Trying to send email now results in the error message below:

```
5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender
```

I know that this account can send messages. I have some batch jobs using PhpMailer that are working fine. There must me some setting in Zend_Mail that I am missing. I really don't want to have to rewrite my Email model to use PhpMailer, but I'm running out of time to get this resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I knew it was something dumb, and that I would figure it out as soon as I posted the question. The problem was that I missed a piece of code that was still setting the "reply-to" address as the old Comcast email address. Looks like Office 365 didn't like that, so the server refused to send the email. Changing that to the correct Office 365 address fixed the problem.

Sorry for answering my own question, but hopefully this will help someone in the future who is facing this problem.

Comment: _but hopefully this will help someone in the future who is facing this problem_

Hah, we have received your message in 2020. For these facing MX migration issue on OVH, especially withing Aschroder_SMTPPro and Magento 1 _5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender_ error on debug this is the thing. General Store Email Address contact should match the SMTP account now. Some solution was already proposed in https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension/pull/276